# voice sms in cordova android

Tags: android, cordova, media, voice-recording

We are working on hydrid apps. Recently we got the requirement to support voice sms. We did R&D on that but we didn't have any luck. So we are trying to record 1 minute voice then we send it to a server. We don't know is it correct way. Please guide to us.

We tried like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-audio-recorder-api

```
    var recorder = new Object;
    function stop(){
    recorder.stop = function() {
      window.plugins.audioRecorderAPI.stop(function(msg) {
        // success 
        alert('ok: ' + msg);
      }, function(msg) {
        // failed 
        alert('ko: ' + msg);
      });
    }}
    function record{
    recorder.record = function() {
      window.plugins.audioRecorderAPI.record(function(msg) {
        // complete 
        alert('ok: ' + msg);
      }, function(msg) {
        // failed 
        alert('ko: ' + msg);
      }, 30); // record 30 seconds 
    }}
   function playback(){
    recorder.playback = function() {
      window.plugins.audioRecorderAPI.playback(function(msg) {
        // complete 
        alert('ok: ' + msg);
      }, function(msg) {
        // failed 
        alert('ko: ' + msg);
      });
    }}
```

We please guide to proper way to achieve our task.

Comment: Did you try to read the code of the library?

https://github.com/emj365/cordova-plugin-audio-recorder-api/blob/master/www/AudioRecorderAPI.js